# Unity launcher icon edges disappeared in 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, launcher, icons

For a couple of days my Unity in Ubuntu 14.04 has been acting weird.

The icon borders in the launcher have disappeared and the indicators are acting strange as well (blocks instead of arrows). All of this is independent of the icon/GTK/window theme in use.

I already reset Unity using [this](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/how-to-reset-compiz-and-unity-in-ubuntu.html) tutorial, but to no avail.

Here is a picture of what is happening:

[image]

I have honestly no idea what might be causing this. The only thing I know is that it happened a few days ago when I forcefully shut down my laptop after a failed file transfer that had absolutely nothing to do with Unity or the OS itself.

Comment: Have you tried removing that theme? it looks like you are using a different theme.

Comment: @Achu Changing/removing theme is not helping unfortunately.

Comment: @Achu After completely purging and removing Numix' PPA and reverting back to Ambiance it did work.

Comment: Good to hear that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity is themable. It appears you are using the Numix GTK theme which does in fact remove the icon borders. You can use *unity-tweak-tool* to switch back to another GTK theme (like Ambiance) if you want to get those border back.

Comment: This worked, but for some strange reason only after purging Numix' PPA. Even if I were to change the theme with Numix installed it, for some reason, still wouldn't display the borders.

Comment: It seems you need to switch the icon theme from one to another (and back) to see the change immediately.