# The Launcher icon edges disappeared after updates

Tags: launcher, icons

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. After receiving updates today the edges in the icons in the launcher disappeared (all the icons have transparent edges, even the ones that have  applications running). 
Anyone else is experiencing the same issue?

Comment: This one http://askubuntu.com/questions/465216/unity-launcher-icon-edges-disappeared-in-14-04 ?

Comment: Noup. That guy was using the Numix GTK theme. I'm using the default ambience theme.

Comment: Did you try to reset Unity?

Comment: I did. It worked, but I think there is an option for enable and disable the borders (because the guest sessions was running as normal) rather than have to reset Unity.